# Compiling c++0x for AVR

Tags: c++, gcc, avr-gcc

I'm currently writing some c++ code for the AVR platform and I'm wanting to disable something that's fundamentally non-copyable. Given that I'm already using c++0x features I thought that a good way to do this would be to use the `=delete` specifier:

```
write_only(write_only const&) = delete;
```

However when I try to compile this I get the following error:

```
error: invalid pure specifier (only `= 0' is allowed) before ';' token
```

This suggests to me that this particular c++0x language feature is not supported by avr-gcc. Is this something I'm doing wrong? If not, what is the best workaround for this?

I'm using WinAVR-20100110 to compile.

Comment: What version is your compiler?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg, I'm using WinAVR-20100110, As to which version of GCC that's based off I'm a bit unsure. I have a suspicion that it might actually be gcc 4.3.2 though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

WinAVR is outdated, use [Atmel Studio](http://www.atmel.com/microsite/atmel_studio6/) instead.

If you really want to continue with WinAVR, find `gcc` or `g++` executable and run it with `-v` command line argument, then tell us what version it reports. Note, that Deleted functions supported in GCC since version 4.4 ([link](http://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx0x.html)).

Anyway, you also must add `-std=gnu++0x` or `-std=c++11` or `-std=gnu++11` parameters when compiling to use C++11 features, or `-std=c++1y` or `-std=gnu++1y` to enable C++14 (C++1y) features.